# syntax error jquery handle json

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firebug says that there's a syntax error near:

```
if (json['name'] !="")
```

But I still can't find it. This is part of a long poll script that hangs until the server sends a response. When the server response is empty, it throws the error near `if (json['name'] !="")`

```
var timestamp=null;
function waitForMsg(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "auth/classes/getdata.php?id="+6,
        async: true,
        cache: false,

        success: function(data){    
            var json=eval('('+data+ ')');
            if (json['name'] !=""){
                if(json['type'] ==1){    
                    $.notification({
                        content: json['name']+" liked a post",
                        showTime: true,
                        icon: '8',
                        timeout: 10000,
                        click: function() {
                            window.location.href = "http://www.test.com/posts.php?post="+json['post'];
                        }
                    });
                }   

                if(json['type'] ==2){
                    $.notification({
                        content: json['name']+" disliked a post",
                        showTime: true,
                        icon: 'Y',
                        timeout: 10000,
                        click: function() {
                            window.location.href = "http://www.test.com/posts.php?post="+json['post'];    
                        }
                    });
                }

                if(json['type'] ==3){    
                    $.notification({
                        content: json['name']+" commented a post",
                        showTime: true,
                        icon: 'i',
                        timeout: 10000,
                        click: function() {
                            window.location.href = "http://www.teest.com/posts.php?post="+json['post'];
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            setTimeout("waitForMsg()",1000);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            // alert("error: "+textStatus + "  "+ errorThrown  );
            setTimeout("waitForMsg()",15000);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
    waitForMsg();     
});
```

Comment: `console.log(json)` show results in question

Comment: What is the structure of the JSON response? Please post an example

Comment: I guess it's eval() method your issue. What is data? Any way you indent your code?!

Comment: id
 "34"
 
name
 "Jamall Fernando"
 
post
 "1506"
 
type
 "3"

Comment: data is a json repose

Comment: Indenting your code properly will help you figure out the problem faster.

Comment: `id "34" name "Jamall Fernando" post "1506" type "3"` is it an object or what? I don't see any key/value

Comment: its an array.. encoded as json from php  response

Comment: if it's php json encoded get rid of `eval` and do `var json=data` and set `dataType`...please properly format code in the future...very hard to read when it's all over the page

Answer (score 1):

```
When the server response is empty, it throws the error near if (json['name'] !="")
```

So check to see if there is data

```
if(!data || !data.length) {
    return;
}
var json=eval('('+data+ ')');
```

Modern day browsers support JSON.parse() and also jQuery will automtically do this for you if you return the correct content type from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use "dataType: 'json'" as an attribute of you ajax call? That would create a json object from the response and you can work directly with that variable.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "auth/classes/getdata.php?id="+6,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

    var json=data; //or you can work directly with data
```

If you return an empty message from your server ("" instead of "{}"), it will trigger the  "error" function of your ajax call, since it will throw a parse exception.

Hope this helps you.

Regards,

Marcelo